# Enable TLS caching with squid. https_port directive support

Tags: caching, proxy, squid

I am trying to enable TLS caching with squid.
Running Squid Cache: Version 6.5 on Ubuntu 24.04
squid-openssl This binary uses OpenSSL 3.0.10 1 Aug 2023. configure options: '--with-openssl' '--enable-ssl-crtd'

My config line:
`https_port 3129 tls-cert=/etc/squid/squid-ca-cert.pem tls-key=/etc/squid/squid-ca-key.pem generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB sslcrtd_program /lib/squid/security_file_certgen -c -s /usr/local/squid/var/cache/squid/ssl_db -M 4MB`

When I add ssl-bump:
`https_port 3129 ssl-bump tls-cert=/etc/squid/squid-ca-cert.pem tls-key=/etc/squid/squid-ca-key.pem generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB`
I get an error:
`FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf line 42: https_port 3129 ssl-bump tls-cert=/etc/squid/squid-ca-cert.pem tls-key=/etc/squid/squid-ca-key.pem generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB`

So far I confirmed Squid configured with required options:
`'--with-openssl' '--enable-ssl-crtd'`

When I run `curl --proxy-insecure --proxy https://localhost:3129` it works, but in the logs I see:

```
1711580401.645    162 192.168.65.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 41698 CONNECT assets-global.website-files.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/54.230.18.101 -
1711580403.972     92 192.168.65.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 41699 CONNECT assets-global.website-files.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/54.230.18.101 -
1711580404.771    103 192.168.65.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 41700 CONNECT assets-global.website-files.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/54.230.18.101 -
```

How do I configure `https_port` on 3129 with TLS so it actually caches requests?